# c++ program to find a file currently open in gvim?

Tags: c++

I want to rename the folder e.g "mv -f old_proj_name new_proj_name".

But, since the file is opened in gvim editor it is not allowing renaming operation to be performed on the folder.

The file is not moved to new folder name.

Manually I have used unlocker software to check whether the file is locked by other process.

fopen() does not show file is locked, when the file is opened by gvim editor.

I tried with opendir() API as well but didn't helped.

Now i want the lock checking functionality to be implemented in my code, so that before doing rename operation i should able to know whether i can do it successfully or not.

Please guide me.

Regards,
Amol

Comment: Just guessing, but are you using cygwin?  Just asking because due to fundamental differences in how files are managed between Windows and unix operating systems this won't work under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> before doing rename operation i should able to know whether i can do it successfully or not.

This is a fallacy. You can only know whether you *could* perform the operation successfully at the time of the check. To know whether you can do it now, you need to check for it *now*. But when you actually get around to performing it, that "now" will turn to "back then". To have a reliable indication, you need to check *again*.

Don't you think it will get tiresome really fast?

So there are two ways of dealing with this.

First, you can hope (but never *know*) that nothing important happens between the check and the actual operation.

Second, you may skip the check altogether and just attempt the operation. If it fails, then you can't do it. There, you have killed two birds with one stone: you have checked whether an operation is possible, and performed it in the case it is indeed possible.

**Update**

If your data is organised in such a way that you have to perform several operations that may fail, and data consistency depends on all these operations succeeding or failing at once, then there's an inherent problem. You can check for some known failure conditions, but (a) you can never check for all possible failure conditions, and (b) any check is valid just for the moment it's performed. So any such check will not be fully reliable. You may be able to prevent some failures but not others. An adequate solution to this would be data storage with proper rollback facility built in, i.e. a database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using cygwin and hamilton shell to execute e.g "mv old_proj_name new_proj_name".

If i perform "mv" operation, then there is no rollback.
That is i cannot rollback to old_proj_name if the command fails.
So that's why i want to know, whether a file has .swp file or not.
Any API which will determine a file is locked or not.

Regards,
Amol.

Comment: If the command fails, the filename remains `old_proj_name`. There's no need to roll back.

Comment: You can check if any `.swp` file exists within your directory, but as I've said, the check is only valid for the very moment it's performed at. If consistency of your data requires that several operations succeed or fail at once (e.g. you need to rename/modify more than one file), then a normal file system is not a reliable storage for such data, you need a file system with roll back built in, or a proper database. Otherwise you can only hope you are quick enough to do everything at once before someone has a chance to screw it up in the middle.

Comment: In my case i have file hierarchy e.g "old_proj_name\path\abc\xyz.txt".
Now when xyz.txt file is opened in gvim editor and now if i execute the command e.g "mv -f old_proj_name new_proj_name".
Then on disk "new_proj_name\path" folder is created.
The file "xyz.txt" and "abc" folder is not moved to new project named folder.

Regards,
Amol

Comment: This is not what I'm seeing on my machine. Perhaps you are trying to move to a different drive.

Comment: No i am moving it on same drive.

Comment: If `mv` on your machine behaves like you describe, it is pretty much broken. Make sure you are using `mv` that comes with cygwin and not any script, alias or a third-party program.

Comment: Well, on the cygwin or Hamilton shell if you execute command "mv -f old_proj_name new_proj_name" then it will work properly. The command will throw an error if the file is opened in gvim editor. But if we run the same command in c++ program using CreateProcess() windows API by filling command line as e.g. "csh -fc \"mv old_proj_name new_proj_name"\" Then the above command will not move the locked file and the folder to new_proj_name

Comment: Why are you using a `csh` clone at all? `csh` is broken for a whole bunch of reasons, and a clone is hardly better. I wouldn't spend a minute of my life troubleshooting it. Switch to `bash`, now. Furthermore, why are you starting an entire shell that runs an entire process to rename a file? What's wrong with `MoveFile` Windows API? It is guaranteed to be atomic if done on the same volume, and it's copy/delete if on different volumes, so if something goes wrong you will have a copy *and* remnants of the old directory.

Comment: Further still, `/bin/mv` should never do what you have described, but if you run `mv` as opposed to `/bin/mv`, all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know about "csh" shell.
But, MoveFile() will work only on Windows. On unix/Linux this API won't work.
So, that's why i want to use "mv" command on the shell, so that it will work on Unix as well.

Comment: You will have to abstract the difference between platforms away. There's no `CreateProcess` on Unix but that's not stopping you from using it. Doing everything platform-dependent in a shell is a pretty roundabout way of abstracting the differences. Why not target POSIX and compile on cygwin?

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion.
One last thing, will it be ok if i check for the existence of .swp file in the "old_proj_name" folder.
And if .swp file exists then i will not perform rename operation.
Will this be a good solution?
Can you please guide me.

Comment: This is a good and useful thing to do, you will remind the user to close the editor. But it's hardly a bulletproof solution.

Comment: By the way, `boost::filesystem` is said to be a good way to access the file system in a portable way.